# PHP5 POST HTML Form Data (inputs data, selection)

Tags: php, html, forms

Having some trouble posting input types data and selections to a php script.

```html
    <form action="./events/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="event" id="event"><br/>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" id="description" ></textarea></br>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></br>
        <input type="date" name="data" id="date"><br/>
        <input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate"><br/>
        <select name="Template" name="Template" id="Template">
            <option value="select1">select 1</option>
            <option value="select2">select 2</option>
            <option value="select3">select 3</option>
            <option value="select4">select 4</option>
        </select><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br/>
        </form>
```

For both text and textbox i can easily get it by using

```
$event = $_REQUEST['event'];
$description = $_REQUEST['description'];
```

If i use the same method to get data, endDate and Template i dont get anything from them.

```
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$endDate = $_REQUEST['enddate'];
$template = $_REQUEST['template'];
$phase = array("Event= ", $event, "Description= ", $description, "Image= ", $image, "Date= ", $date, "End Date= ", $endDate, "Template= ", $template);
print_r($phase);
```

I am simply looking to get the data they have as a sting (so date as a string and the Template value as a string.

Comment: Side note: Did you in fact close off the form? I don't see a `</form>` in your post and in edit mode neither.

Comment: *"If i use the same method to get data..."* - Did you assign those variables to POST arrays?

Comment: i did close off the form sorry, and i used their name ="" values for the requests.

Comment: i have tried $_POST with no change. still getting nothing from those fields

Comment: Anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You should be getting errors, `$_REQUEST['template']` and `name="Template" name="Template"` is doubled, yet the lettercase is different. Same thing goes for `name="endDate"`. Both being undefined indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the array key's you are trying to access are case sensitive:

this will work:

```
$date = $_REQUEST['data'];
$endDate = $_REQUEST['endDate'];
$template = $_REQUEST['Template'];
$phase = array("Event= ", $event, "Description= ", $description, "Image= ", $image, "Date= ", $date, "End Date= ", $endDate, "Template= ", $template);
print_r($phase);
```

to find errors like these it's a good practice to turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: i moved over from ajax to include file uploading and forgot to check the naming scheme, thanks.